# Unable to perform search suggestions and search operation using single searchview

Tags: android

I have a search bar in my app, when I click on it recent suggestions should be shown and when i click on a suggestion search operation should be performed as it happens through this function

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
}
}
```

my problem is suggestions can be shown but when i click on it search operation is not performed

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions

Comment: search suggestions can be performed by using above link but i wanted to perform both